# How to put a form in a php function

Tags: php, forms, paypal, echo

I have this part of a function:

```
echo "{$obj->notice("uonline")} {$obj->notice("useronline")}.<br/>";
```

Instead of having that, i want to add a paypal doante button, which starts with form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="private">
                        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>
```

the problem is, that when I paste the code above between the echo " ", all the colors of the rest or the page changes, and the part where it says method="post" target="_blank" appears in green in notepad++, my question is how to put that paypal code in echo without it failing? thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the quotes `"`? Do you have any PHP basics?

Comment: have you tried using `echo '(code)';` rather than using double quotes?